# For PDFs over 900 pages, how can I place multiple pages on 1 sheet without increasing file size?

Tags: pdf

1. For PDFs over 900 pages ([Sedja](https://www.sejda.com/n-up-pdf]) cannot help with its limit of 200 pages), are there other methods to allocate or impose a number (selected by me) of previously individual pages to 1 sheet, besides using some PDF printer to print multiple pages per sheet?
2. With Foxit PhantomPDF<sup>1</sup>, I am trying to print every 2 pages onto 1 sheet of paper; but the problem is the resultant excessive surge in  file size: the original of 14 MB surges to 230 MB! How can I solve this problem? I screenshot the settings used:[image]

<sup>1</sup>I have abandoned Adobe Acrobat Pro XI for Foxit PhantomPDF as the latter is easier to use with its comfortable layout (based on MS Office).

Comment: I assume you're asking for a software to solve described issue, am I correct? If so, can you please clarify: for what OS (assuming Windows here?), what's your budget, what other features should it have, must it allow for commercial use, etc? Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You might better look at imposing programs or plug-ins for Acrobat.

Just so, [Quite Imposing by Quite Software](http://www.quite.com/imposing/) comes to my mind.

Refrying (that's essentially what you do when "printing" to PDF is generally not recommended (as it removes too much from the PDF), unless you know what you are doing.

Another possibility would be creating a double-page PDF from the original document.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Link added in message; thanks for the reminder.